# iTerm shortcut на alt+b, alt+f

Tags: macos, терминал

Вместо навигации по словам, сверху всплывает прозрачное окно терминала.
Срабатывает даже когда iTerm не активен.
Где это можно отключить?

**P.S.** в iTerm в не нашел alt+b ни alt+f